# how to make sure that img returned from the server side can not be intercepted

Tags: javascript, flash, encryption

In our application,we have a web service which wll return images to the client according to the parameter.

Now,we want to make sure that the image can not be used by no-permissioned user and can not be intercepted through the network.

So we want to encrypt the image in the server side,when the client get the image,it should be decrypted accordingly. However our application is browser based. It seems that in the browser we can not use javascript to decrpte the image stream.

Assume that each client which call the service is absolute safe.

We try to use a hidden flash in the page,which may decrpte the image and save them to local,then show them in the page, this will use the communications between the js and flash.

But we have to decrype the image use the flash language other than c# or java.

So I want to know if there is any solution to meet my requirement?

ALso if there is another better manner?

**UPDATE:**

Our service for servering images:

```
http://xxx/getImage?row=1&col=3
```

This url is public,so any one can use this service with different paramter.

Even we add a key paramete like this:

```
http://xxx/getImage?row=1&col=3&key=SDSGSDSKDFEKYESLWQODLSFKDS
```

THen we meet two problem:
1)how about other people know this key,even we bind the key with the ip or mac addresss.

2)How about the user grap the http package directly? Then he do not need know any parameter,he can intercept the whole image steam.

**UPDATE2**

Is there is a solution using both server side and client side?

That's to say,does using flash will work or not?

Comment: the key should be disabled after 5 min. :)

The real problem here is your goal. You can't protect an Image on the internet. Best solution is to watermark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serve the image, and the entire of the page that calls the image, over HTTPS instead of unencrypted HTTP.

There is no need to involve any kind of client side programming. SSL encryption support is built into browsers.

> how about other people know ths key,even we bind the key with the ip or mac addresss.

They don't. That's the point of secret keys.

> How about the user grap the http package directly? Then he do not need know any parameter,he can intercept the whole image steam.

They can't. That's the point of SSL encryption.

Comment: how about if the hacker know the url for example:<>https://xxx/xx.png''? Since the service for server the images are pubic

Comment: We want that even the hacker know the image url,he will only get the encrypted image.

Comment: Handing a Flash application (or whatever) over to any client that asks for it wouldn't help with that. You need to either keep the URLs secret (from the general public) or use some form of authentication.

Comment: @hguser — Updated the answer in response.

Comment: Seems a good idea. Is https  safe enougth that can not be intercepted?

Comment: Safe enough for all online banking to depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your particuliar requirement. Is it to save bandwidth so that if someone steal your image it won't cost you or you just want to protect the image?

Because if that's the later then just forget it. Once the image is displayed on the internet nothing will prevent it from spreading. If you display it in a Flash application users will just use (printscreen) and paste it in a new image. If you don't use flash, users will just right-click and then select "Save Image to".

Now if it's for the first point, then a simple check server side on the referer of the request is enough on 99% of the cases. And if you really wanna hide the url, then there's no easy solution. You'd have to create a script server side that sends the image depending on the key you give him.

So something like : Bob enters page A -> (Server knows this page contains image A and image B and generate 2 keys for Bob) -> The image urls are likes /image.aspx?key=mykeytoimageA -> key is disabled after 5min.

Comment: BTW,we have assumed that the client which call our service is safe,so we do not care if they save the image to local or not. For your manner,"image.aspx?key=mykeytoimageA",once it is requested from the network,it can be intercepted. So we think the best manner is encrypte the image and decrtypte the image in the client side.

Comment: Then add an https Layer to that... and prevent the key from working again once it has been called once.

Comment: (That's how the eBook sellers do by the way. You generate a download token, which is only valid for a short period of time and is single use. Then you send the content over https)

Answer (score -1):

Any server side programming language can return an image.  So, let's say that you are using PHP.

You could make a call to PHP to get the image:

```
<img src="get_image.php?id=12" />
```

Inside the PHP file, you would have your security validation and then set the header to type "image/*"

You can do this in pretty much any server side language.  Just do a search on "return image type in langauge x"